# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string "v2.6.5.2"

Tags: java

I'm working on an implementation of an RPC(JSON) system in java and I'm experiencing an error answering one of the calls.

```
SperoCoin.java

1 package com.l2spero.gameserver.handler.voicedcommandhandlers;
2    public class SperoCoin
3    {
4       public NpcHtmlMessage nhm = new NpcHtmlMessage(5);
5       public TextBuilder replyMSG = new TextBuilder("");
6       
7       public String address = "127.0.0.1";
8       public int port = 55681;
9       public String protocol = "http";
10      public String user = "user";
11      public String password = "password";
12      
13      BitcoindApi api = BitcoindApiFactory.createConnection(address, port, protocol, user, password);
14    
15      
16      public void getInfo(String[] args) throws BitcoindConnector4JException
17      {
18          try {
19              Info info = api.getinfo();
20              BlockchainInfo getblockchaininfo = api.getblockchaininfo();
21              
22                  replyMSG.append("<html><title>SPEROCOIN WALLET</title><body>");
23                  replyMSG.append("<font color=\"FFFF00\"><center>L2SPERO WALLET</center></font>");
24                  replyMSG.append("<font color=\"FFFF00\"><center>Version:" + info.getVersion() + "</center></font>");
25                  replyMSG.append("<font color=\"FFFF00\"><center>Protocol Version:" + info.getProtocolversion() + "</center></font>");
26                  replyMSG.append("<font color=\"FFFF00\"><center>Wallet Version:" + info.getWalletversion() + "</center></font>");
27                  replyMSG.append("<font color=\"FFFF00\"><center>Chain:" + getblockchaininfo.getChain() + "</center></font>");
28                  replyMSG.append("<font color=\"FFFF00\"><center>Blocks:" + info.getBlocks() + "</center></font>");
29                  replyMSG.append("</body></html>");
30                  
31          }catch (Exception e) {
32              e.printStackTrace();
33          }
34      }
35    }
```

The file above displays the text I need within the JAVA application, but line 24, when I run the command I get the error:

*Failed reading: [C] 38 Say2 ; java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "v2.6.5.2: Beta 2.6.5.2"
com.l2spero.sperocoin.core.BitcoindConnector4JException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "v2.6.5.2: Beta 2.6.5.2"*

The Info.java file that makes the calls inside the external application and returns the results in JSON is this:

```
package com.l2spero.sperocoin.response;

public class Info extends BaseResponse {

    private Double balance;
    private long blocks;
    private long connections;
    private Double difficulty;
    private String errors;
    private long keypoololdest;
    private long keypoolsize;
    private Double paytxfee;
    private long protocolversion;
    private String proxy;
    private Double relayfee;
    private boolean testnet;
    private long timeoffset;
    private long version;
    private long walletversion;

    public Double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(Double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public long getBlocks() {
        return blocks;
    }

    public void setBlocks(long blocks) {
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }

    public long getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }

    public void setConnections(long connections) {
        this.connections = connections;
    }

    public Double getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(Double difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    public String getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(String errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public long getKeypoololdest() {
        return keypoololdest;
    }

    public void setKeypoololdest(long keypoololdest) {
        this.keypoololdest = keypoololdest;
    }

    public long getKeypoolsize() {
        return keypoolsize;
    }

    public void setKeypoolsize(long keypoolsize) {
        this.keypoolsize = keypoolsize;
    }

    public Double getPaytxfee() {
        return paytxfee;
    }

    public void setPaytxfee(Double paytxfee) {
        this.paytxfee = paytxfee;
    }

    public long getProtocolversion() {
        return protocolversion;
    }

    public void setProtocolversion(long protocolversion) {
        this.protocolversion = protocolversion;
    }

    public String getProxy() {
        return proxy;
    }

    public void setProxy(String proxy) {
        this.proxy = proxy;
    }

    public Double getRelayfee() {
        return relayfee;
    }

    public void setRelayfee(Double relayfee) {
        this.relayfee = relayfee;
    }

    public boolean getTestnet() {
        return testnet;
    }

    public void setTestnet(boolean testnet) {
        this.testnet = testnet;
    }

    public long getTimeoffset() {
        return timeoffset;
    }

    public void setTimeoffset(long timeoffset) {
        this.timeoffset = timeoffset;
    }

    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public long getWalletversion() {
        return walletversion;
    }

    public void setWalletversion(long walletversion) {
        this.walletversion = walletversion;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GetInfo [balance=" + balance + ", blocks=" + blocks + ", connections=" + connections + ", difficulty="
                + difficulty + ", errors=" + errors + ", keypoololdest=" + keypoololdest + ", keypoolsize="
                + keypoolsize + ", paytxfee=" + paytxfee + ", protocolversion=" + protocolversion + ", proxy=" + proxy
                + ", relayfee=" + relayfee + ", testnet=" + testnet + ", timeoffset=" + timeoffset + ", version="
                + version + ", walletversion=" + walletversion + "]";
    }

}
```

The return in JSON in the source application is this:

```
{
"version" : "v2.6.5.2: Beta 2.6.5.2",
"protocolversion" : 700004,
"walletversion" : 60000,
"balance" : 0.00000000,
"newmint" : 0.00000000,
"stake" : 0.00000000,
"blocks" : 1326067,
"timeoffset" : -1,
"moneysupply" : 194143.36538519,
"connections" : 4,
"proxy" : "",
"ip" : "0.0.0.0",
"difficulty" : {
"proof-of-work" : 0.00277217,
"proof-of-stake" : 0.00024414
},
"testnet" : false,
"keypoololdest" : 1613136757,
"keypoolsize" : 101,
"paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
"mininput" : 0.00000000,
"isunlocked" : true,
"unlocked_until" : 0,
"errors" : ""
}
```

Comment: What long value do you expect  "v2.6.5.2: Beta 2.6.5.2" to get converted to ?

Comment: I have little knowledge in JAVA, but the return I believe should come in String for him different types of characters, besides space.
By the way I updated the topic as the source application returns the command getinfo in its console.
Thanks!

Comment: `"version"` in the JSON is a string, not a Long, so dont store it as a Long

Comment: When I change to String in fields where they are long, I get the following return:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected NUMBER but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $.difficulty`

Comment: Same kind of error: `difficulty` in the JSON is an object by itself, but in your Java code it's a `Double`. The JSON object cannot be converted to a `Double`.

Comment: Thank you so much Jasper!
Double would be where there are decimal places, no?
In the case of version, it would be a string just like in proxy or errors.

Comment: Even if you stripped all non-numeric characters out of the version, you still wouldn't have a number. That's a software version *string*

Answer (score 1):

Field in Info class is long

But in json it is String

So i think you need to change type of version in java class to string

Comment: I came to do this, even commented above, but it generated another error in the same direction.